# extracting text from a specific <h> element using GetElementById

Tags: html, dom, vbscript

I have created a VBS script file that looks at an XML data file. 
Within the XML data file, the HTML data I need is embedded within the

```
<![CDATA[]'other interesting HTML data here'].
```

I have stripped out this HTML data using XPATH and insterted into a Div object (myDiv) element that is represented as a variable (its not written to a document). 
So for example, the contents of     myDiv.innerHTML looks like this;

```
<table> 
<tr><td>text in cell 1</td></tr> 
<tr><td><h1 id="myId1">my text for H1</h></td><tr> 
<tr><td><h2 id="myId2">my text for h2</h></td></tr> 
</table>
```

What I want to do at first is simply select the appropriate tag with the Id that matches "myId1", therefore, I used a statement like this;

```
MyIdText = MyDiv.getElementById("myId1")
```

However, the aplpication I am using says "Err 438, Object doesn't support this property or method". 
I am a bit of a newbie with code and can understand some of the basic fundamantals, but get a bit lost when it becomes a bit more complex (sorry). I have looked through other postings on this board, and all of them seem to rlate to HTML nad Javascript, not VBScript (the application I am using will not allow Java Script).
Am I using the code wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To use getElementById() you should write: document.getElementById("myId1"). This way you tell the browser to search inside 'document' for the specified ID. Your variable is not defined and it does not have this method attached, so your code will generate the above error.

To extract the text inside the specific H element:

`MyIdText = document.getElementById("myId1").textContent;`

Comment: I have extracted the html from an XML file, created a <div> element and inserted the html into the <div> element. The html doean't actually exist in a document, it exists in the MyDiv element variable. I am able to perform a GetElementsByTagName operation on the MyDiv element but the GetElementById operation doesn't seem to work. I am also using VBS not JavaScript....I'll try and work through it

Answer (score 0):

many thanks for the help, unfortunately, I know a little VBS and even littler about DOM and I am trying to learn both by experimenting. There are certain restrictions within the environment/application I am working with (Its called ASCE and its a tool for managing Safety Cases - but thats not important right now).
However, so that we are comparing apples with apples, I have tried to experiment within an HTML page to give me a better understanding of what the DOM/VBS commands can actually do. I have had some partial success, but still cant understand why it falls over where it does.
Here is the exact file I am experimenting with, I have added comment text for each section;

```
<html>
<head>

<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td>text in cell 1</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><h1 id="myId1">my text for H1</h1></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><h1 id="myId2">my text for h2</h2></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/vbscript">
DoStuff

Sub DoStuff 

    ' Section 1: Get a node with the Id value of "myId1" from the above HTML
    ' and assign it to the variable 'GetValue'
    ' This works fine :-)
    Dim GetValue
    GetValue = document.getElementById("myId1").innerHTML
    MsgBox "the text=" & GetValue   

    ' Section 2: Create a query that assigs to the variable 'MyH1Tags' to  all of the <h1> 
    ' tags in the document.
    ' I assumed that this would be a 'collection of <h1> tags so I set up a loop to itterate
    ' through however many there were, but this fails as the browser says that this object 
    ' doesn't support this property or method - This is where I am stuck    

    Dim MyH1Tags    
    Dim H1Tag
    MyH1Tags = document.getElementsByTagName("h1") ' this works

    For Each H1Tag in MyH1Tags ' this is where it falls over
        MSgbox "Hello"
    Next


    ' Section 3: Create a new Div element 'NewDiv' and then insert some HTML 'MyHTML'
    ' into 'NewDiv'. Create a query 'MyHeadings' that extracts all h1 headings from 'NewDiv'
    ' then loop round for however many h1 headings there are in 'MyHeadings'
    ' and display the text content. This works Ok

    Dim NewDiv  
    Dim MyHTML  
    Dim MyHeadings
    Dim MyHeading
    Set NewDiv = document.createElement("DIV")      
    MyHTML="<h1 id=""a"">heading1</h1><h2 id=""b"">Heading2</h2>"  
    NewDiv.innerHTML=MyHTML
    Set MyHeadings = NewDiv.getElementsByTagName("h1")

    For Each MyHeading in MyHeadings
        Msgbox "MyHeading=" & MyHeading.innerHTML
    Next


    'Section 4: Do a combination of Section 1 (that works) and Section 3 (that works)
    ' by creating a new Div element 'NewDiv2' and then paste into it some HTML
    ' 'MyHTML2' and then attempt to create a query that extracts  the inner HTML from 
    ' an id attribute with the value of "a". But this doesnt work either.
    ' I have tried "Set MyId = NewDiv2.getElementById("a").innerHTML" and
    ' also tried "Set MyId = NewDiv2.getElementById("a")" and it always falls over 
    ' at the same line.
    Dim NewDiv2 
    Dim MyHTML2     
    Dim MyId

    Set NewDiv2 = document.createElement("DIV")     
    MyHTML2="<h1 id=""a"">heading1</h1><h2 id=""b"">Heading2</h2>"  
    NewDiv2.innerHTML=MyHTML

    MyId = NewDiv2.getElementById("a").innerHTML

End Sub

</script>
</head>

<body>
```